# Enum error 'member" is not a type of "Enum"

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using `KolodaView` library: https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda

In this library, there's a publicly defined function in its `delegate` method:

```
func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, didSwipeCardAtIndex index: UInt, inDirection direction: SwipeResultDirection) {}
```

The `SwipeResultDirection` is a enum, which is defined in the library:

```
public enum SwipeResultDirection: String {
  case Left
  case Right
  ...
}
```

But when I access it in my `ViewController`, it has the error of

> `'Right" is not a type of "SwipeResultDirection"`

Here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var kolodaView: KolodaView!
}

extension ViewController: KolodaViewDelegate {
  func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, didSwipeCardAtIndex index: UInt, inDirection direction: SwipeResultDirection.Right) {
    // Error here
    return
  }
}
```

Comment: As I can see, here You have function declaration, not calling it. Put: `func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, didSwipeCardAtIndex index: UInt, inDirection direction: SwipeResultDirection) {`

Comment: Oh, I thought it's used the same way as `tableViewDelegate`. So how do I call it, since I can manually pass `direction` as parameter?

Comment: You don't call it. From github I see that it is called just before swipe. And You need to implement it to tell caller if swipe can be done or not. What You want to achive, BTW?

Comment: I want to print "Apple" if I swipe to the right, and "Cherry" if I swipe to the left. Is it OK to ask you to create a working example with the `Example` project?

Comment: See my answer and tell if it is what You want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this framework, but I think it should be some of this:

```
extension ViewController: KolodaViewDelegate {
    func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, didSwipeCardAtIndex index: UInt, inDirection direction: SwipeResultDirection) {
        if direction == .Right {
            print("Apple")
        } else if direction == .Left {
            print("Cherry")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to print anything though, it solved the bug, thanks bro!